# Undefined reference with cmake using own libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I have the folllowing directory structure:

```
-project

  -helper
    -build
    -include
      -h_a.h
      -h_b.h
    -src
      -h_a
        -h_a.cpp
        -CMakeLists.txt
      -h_b
        -h_b.cpp
        -CMakeLists.txt
      -CMakeLists.txt

  -proj_c
    -build
    -src
      -main.cpp
      -CMakeLists.txt
```

In the `helper` project two libraries are generated: `libh_a.a` and `libh_b.a`. `libh_a.a` is used to build `libh_b.a`. The files are the following:

`helper/src/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

project(helper)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -g -std=c++11")

add_subdirectory(h_a)
add_subdirectory(h_b)
```

`helper/src/h_a/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
project(h_a)

add_library(h_a h_a.cpp)
```

`helper/src/h_a/h_a.cpp`

```
void func_a(){}
```

`helper/src/h_b/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
project(h_b)

add_library(h_b h_b.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    h_b STATIC
    h_a
)
```

`helper/src/h_b/h_b.cpp:`

```
#include "../../include/h_a.h"

void func_b(){
    func_a();   
}
```

`proj_c/src/CMakeLists.txt:`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2)

project(proj_c)

find_library(h_a PATHS ../../helper/build/h_a)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../helper/build/h_a)

find_library(h_b PATHS ../../helper/build/h_b)
link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../helper/build/h_b)

set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "../bin/")

add_executable(proj_c main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(
    proj_c
    h_a
    h_b
)
```

`proj_c/src/main.cpp:`

```
#include "../../helper/include/h_b.h"

int main(){
    func_b();
}
```

First I run `cmake ../src` from `helper/build` (no error messsages) than `cmake ../src` from `proj_c/build` and I got

```
proj_c/src/../../helper/build/h_b/libh_b.a(h_b.cpp.o): In function `func_b()':
helper/src/h_b/h_b.cpp:4: undefined reference to `func_a()'
```

It seems that the problem is with `h_b.cpp`, but `libh_b.a` was built previously without errors.

Comment: Unrelated generic CMake suggestion: `set( CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11 )` to set C++11 platform-independently. Set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` to `Debug` (instead of adding `-g` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS`) to get debug information compiled in platform-independently. Check for `CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC` before setting `-Wall`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first problem is that your libraries aren't found. In `proj_c/build/CMakeCache.txt`:

```
//Path to a library.
h_a:FILEPATH=h_a-NOTFOUND

//Path to a library.
h_b:FILEPATH=h_b-NOTFOUND
```

(Use the `DOC` option to `find_library()` to get the generic "Path to a library" replaced with something more helpful.)

This kind of "silent failure" can be overcome by adding a check after `find_library()`:

```
if ( NOT h_a )
    message( FATAL_ERROR "Library h_a not found in ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../helper/build/h_a" )
endif()
```

(For larger projects you will have a `FindXyz.cmake` module set up for finding dependencies, which you can call via `find_package( Xyz REQUIRED )` to avoid silent failure. But that, and the helper functions available to you when writing such a module, are a subject all of its own.)

The failure itself is due to a problem with your use of `find_library`:

```
find_library(h_a PATHS ../../helper/build/h_a)
```

You tell CMake where to look, and in which variable to store the result, *but not what to look **for**.*

Use:

```
find_library(h_a NAMES h_a PATHS ../../helper/build/h_a)
```

This will resolve the `-NOTFOUND`. (Apply for `h_b` as well.)

You will still get the linker error though, because of...

```
target_link_libraries(
    proj_c
    h_a
    h_b
)
```

...linking order. `proj_c` looks for `func_b()`, does not find it in `h_a`, *does* find it in `h_b`, which in turn requires `func_a()`, *which isn't found* because the linker is making a single pass over the library list only.

It's the same with specifyling `-lh_a -lh_b` on the command line.

Switch the libraries around according to the dependency chain (`proj_c` depends on `h_b` depends on `h_a`):

```
target_link_libraries(
    proj_c
    h_b
    h_a
)
```

That will work.